# Does grails support using "forEach" from JSTL core taglib in gsp page?

Tags: grails, foreach, jstl, gsp

I had the problem in writing the gsp page using grails. The page works fine with other tags from JSTL core taglib, such as c:if, c:when. But I could not get it work when I was using c:forEach for looping. Following are the code snippets:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
......
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${fooList}" varStatus="counter">
    ${counter.count}, ${foo}
</c:forEach>
```

The errors from Grails shows that the implicit object counter is null.

```
Error 500: null
Servlet: 
URI: 
Exception Message: Cannot get property 'count' on null object 
Caused by: Error evaluating expression [counter.count] on line [16]: Cannot get property 'count' on null object
```

From the Grails documentation, it is said that JSP tags are supported.

==>> "http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3.6 Using JSP Tag Libraries"

But I just could not get c:forEach to work, which works fine as a jsp page instead of having a gsp suffix.

Grails Version: 1.37
JDK: 1.6.0_22

Answer (score 8):

It's much better to use standard GSP's for each:

```
<g:each var="foo" in="${fooList}" status="counter">
    ${counter.count}, ${foo}
</g:each>
```

Comment: thanks, it should be a preferred way for doing that. I am just working on a legacy project and want to know if it is supported or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<g:each var="foo" in="${fooList}" status="counter">
    ${counter}, ${foo}
</g:each>
```

I was having the same problem...
Then I figured out that it was ${counter} instead of ${counter.count} to get the item number to show up.